# Table has no natural keys in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design

The AP database example provided online by Murach's SQL Server 2016 for developers has an Invoice table with the surrogate key InvoiceID but with no natural keys. Most of the other tables have natural keys that uniquely identify each row, so I was curious: why would they provide a table without a natural key to identify what each row represents?

I got the AP database creation script from here:
https://www.murach.com/shop/murach-s-sql-server-2016-for-developers-detail

[image]

Comment: Isn't  `InvoiceID` the primary key of table `Invoice`?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: This is probably a question to ask the book's authors. However, shouldn't `InvoceNumber` be a good natural key candidate, as it's non-nullable and probably should be unique?

Comment: If InvoiceID is the primary key, then by definition it uniquely identifies the row.  If the primary key does not include other fields then there could be business logic involved.  A lot of times a single column will be used as the PK (for clustering purposes) and other unique non-clustered indexes will be created to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Most RDMS SQL related engines are designed to insert faster into a *"order"* in a file if that file is table or a index file does not matter.. A surrogate key can provide a fix insert "order" as the positions to insert are predicatable where a natural key can have a different random inserting order on every insert...That would also slow down inserting into a B tree index structure (comment is over simplified..)

Comment: Most RDMS SQL related engines are designed to insert faster into a *"order"* in a file if that file is table or a index file does not matter.. A surrogate key can provide a fix insert *"order"* as the positions to insert are predicatable where a natural key can have a different random inserting *"order"* on every insert...That would also slow down inserting into a B tree index structure (comment is over simplified..)  .. That said that might be the reason why they not added in a natural key aswell, still it is a bit wierd as the invoiceID and invoiceNumber clearly can have different data..

Comment: *"Most RDMS SQL related engines are designed to insert faster into a "order" in a file if that file is table or a index file does not matter."* .. SQL Server it not different and can do that aswell with [clustering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15) is used  .. note i said *"order"*, as SQL language is still defined as **orderless** you should not be trusting getting a order when selecting without using the use off `ORDER BY`

Comment: Quite simply - a generic invoice has no natural key. Whether InvoiceNumber can be considered a natural key is a question for the designers of the database and the actual (if any) real system on which the database is modeled. However, this question is off-topic for multiple reasons. Seems like [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) is a slightly better fit since this is not really coding-related.

Comment: @SMor The Database-design tag is not coding related and it is part of SO, IMHO this is an appropriate question.

Comment: *"The Database-design tag is not coding related and it is part of SO, IMHO this is an appropriate question."* no nicomp, @SMor is right this is a primary a opinion-based question which is considerd offtopic here..

Comment: @RaymondNijland A natural key is an industry standard. A table in a real-world application has a natural key.

Comment: *"A natural key is an industry standard. A table in a real-world application has a natural key"* Not what i meant, besides that it not a standard it it is just professional jargon terminology and i never said a table never would have or should have a natural key  .. @SMor pretty much nailed it with this comment as somebody like SMor  opinion could be is that invoiceNumber is not suitable for a natural key, where we/you or me can find it is that is suitable which makes it primary opinion-based .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they made a mistake. The natural key here presumably ought to be (VendorID, InvoiceNumber). I have never seen a real accounts payable system that allowed duplicate invoice numbers for the same vendor. Paying the same invoice twice obviously isn't a good idea!

The most common motivation for creating a surrogate is to reduce the impact of having to change other key values. Natural key (AKA business key) values sometimes need to change. Surrogate keys need to change much less frequently because fewer people ever see them and so there's much less reason to change them. That relative stability may have some technical advantages in situations where the business key values are expected to change. Even in the presence of a surrogate, business keys are still critically important because they are the things that users and business processes depend on.

Comment: I once ran into a client whose system did not allow for the detection of a double entry of a single invoice, due to human error.  They brushed off my questions about data normalization,  so I asked them whet they did when a customer complains about double billing.  They said,  "we could never figure it out, so we just issue a credit to any customer who complains about duplicate billing."  No kidding,  this really happened!

Answer (score 1):

An invoice is a man made piece of data.  That's all it is.  It has no natural key,  because it has no natural identifier.  The person or process who creates a new invoice assigns it a number, call it Invoice Number.  But that number is just as artificial as Invoice.Id would be.  If you want to consider one of those a surrogate, go ahead.

An automobile is a man made piece of gear,  but it isn't just data.  It's something to drive around.  When a new automobile is made it gets assigned a unique identifier,  called the Vehicle Identification Number,  or VIN.  But that key is ultimately just as artificial as Invoice Number.  It's just pulled out of thin air,  made so that it will be unique, and assigned to the car. There is nothing more "Natural" about VIN than there is about Invoice Number.  And there is nothing less "natural" about identifiers that are chosen by the DBMS, perhaps using an autonumber feature.

**Edit in response to comments:** VIN is assigned at the business level, but it's sole legitimate function is to identify a vehicle.  There are rules for its formation, but those rules exist to prevent the same VIN from being assigned to two vehicles.  If one of the digits in the VIN says the seating capacity of the vehicle,  that's the seating capacity on the day of manufacture.  It's possible to change the seating capacity of a vehicle after it's in operation,  by ripping out one of the seats.

If all keys that are used by the business domain (alternatively the "conceptual domain") are natural,  it must be recognized that in certain businesses a key will be generated inside a computerized system and eventually acquire meaning as it is used at the business layer.  Arguments have been made in answers to other questions that surrogate keys should never be revealed to the application user, or perhaps even to the application program,  lest it begin to be used in a meaningful way.  That's ultimately a philosophical question,  and not one of database design.

Comment: *"An invoice is a man made piece of data. That's all it is. It has no natural key, because it has no natural identifier. The person or process who creates a new invoice assigns it a number, call it Invoice Number"* A natural key is a key used to identify things in the business domain meaning the real world live data outside the database.     a piece off information like a invoiceNumber is/can be a perfect natural key to use..

Comment: Also VIN is not pulled out of thin air there is a spec how ViN is defined like so that makes it simply a business domain also suitable as a natural key

Comment: In this context *natural* doesn't mean something that must exist in the wild. Our use of the phrase "natural key" means that the columns composing that key have meaning in the conceptual design of the problem being solved by the schema. A VIN could be a natural key because is has meaning in the real world. A unique serial number assigned to each row in a table by the IDENTITY feature of SQL Server is not a natural key because it has no meaning outside the RDBMS. We need a name for this non-natural key so we agree to call it a surrogate key.

Comment: *"IDENTITY is not a natural key because it has no meaning outside the RDBMS."* Still debatable @nicomp imagine a factory which just started to make products and defined there outside article number to be simply a `IDENTITY` column then it would/could serve as a surrogate and a natural key in one go as this article number fits into the business domain (wierd example which most likely never happens i know but still). Anyhow now you know why primarily opinion-based is offtopic as answers to this kind off questions will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts or references

Comment: Not really contradicting @nicomp like i said it was a wierd example which most likely never happens.. But think about it for a while... if a article number is generated by the RDMS and can be used outside the company to make orders on it fits into a business domain (the real world live data outside the database)... You and i already said that some unique business domain data could be suitable natural keys to use..

Comment: *All* natural keys are assigned by a person or a machine. There are no exceptions. Invoice Numbers and VINs are examples of "natural" keys because they are real world identifiers that are part of an external business process rather than surrogates that exist only inside systems. "Business Key" is a better term than natural key but it means the same thing.

Comment: *"Business Key" is a better term than natural key but it means the same thing.* -- very helpful. I will use that!

Comment: I see what some of you are saying.  Natural keys have meaning in the business domain, while surrogate keys do not.  Fair enough, and I'll have to go back and edit my answer to reflect that fact.  But there are complexities in this formula as well.  For example,  an id can be generated inside the DBMS as a meaningless but unique number,  and then acquire meaning in the business domain because the users of the information system begin to use the number as if it had meaning.  Example:  help desk asks customer "what's your customer ID?" .  ID was originally assigned by the DBMS.

Comment: Yes of course. Customer ID is certainly a natural key if it is what the customer uses to identify him/herself to the helpdesk. The term natural key relates to how the key is used and not how it is generated. Lots of natural keys get generated inside software (e.g. order numbers, login names, URLs, SKUs, barcodes, tax identifiers, bank account numbers, phone numbers)

Comment: Thanks,@nvogel.  In that case Customer.ID could become a natural key as well, if it were to begin to be used that way.  Or,  for that matter,  Invoice.ID.

Comment: Sure, but by convention invoices are usually identified by something called an invoice number. Having two different numeric business keys for an invoice seems unnecessary and probably a recipe for confusion. The OP stated that Invoice ID is a surrogate rather than a natural key so my answer was based on that assumption.

Comment: Again, a very helpful comment.  But it raises the question, why ever have a surrogate key, instead of always using natural keys?  As a practical matter, I have seen an ID field used, in addition to a natural key in order to allow the DBMS to assure uniqueness and immutability in an arena where the business cannot be trusted to avoid screwing up the natural key.

Comment: These comments are turning into a conversation.  I'd love to chat with you, but maybe elsewhere.

Comment: I updated my answer with a note about the reason for surrogate keys.